# Calculating $n$-th $q:P(q)=p \in \Bbb P$

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, prime-numbers

Let $P(x)$ denote the number of ways of writing an integer $x$ as a sum of positive integers (where permutation of the array of integers in the sum doesn't count).

Ex: $P(1)=1, P(2)=2,P(4)=5$.

Let $Q(n)$ denote the function that gives the $n$-th argument $q_n$ such that $P(q_n)$ is prime.

$Q(1)=2 \iff P(2)=2, Q(2)=3 \iff P(3)=3, Q(3)=4 \iff P(4)=5$, etc.

I don't think there's going to be an easy way to find a closed form of $Q(n)$, but what about an estimate, and also a simpler function that behaves asymptotically similar to $Q$?

Comment: The values $Q(n)$ are the sequence [A046063](https://oeis.org/A046063).